# A graph of f(x) looks like a curve drawn on a square. Is there a working definition of curves that would intersect the top side of the square?

Tags: curves, plane-curves

Some functions who would seem to intersect it on top: $y=x^2$, $y=x^3$, $x=0$, $y=xa$ for a high enough $a$, $y=\tan x$, $y = \frac{1}{x}$

For instance, $y = x^2$:

[image]

Curves that do not fit: $y=0$, $y = \sqrt{x}$, $y = \ln x$, $y = \cos x$, $y = \sin x$.

For instance, $y = \sqrt{x}$

[image]

Naturally, this depends on the extent to which one zooms in or out on the origin. But I'd like to know how, for instance, we could speak of an infinite outwards zoom, or an infinite inwards zoom on the origin. Some graphs look exactly the same whether we zoom in or out! $x = y$ for instance.

A close enough zoom on $x^2$ makes it such that it stops intersecting the square on top:
[image]

An excellent example given by user Mason in the comments is: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y3zeqnnybk
What functions would intersect the top side on this square as it gets infinitely bigger?

Comment: Which square(s) do you mean? It would help if you explained *why* your examples work, and *why* your counter-examples don't work (and what you're getting at with the zooming). Images might be useful here. (Please add any clarifications to the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.)

Comment: @Blue added some pictures!

Comment: You can get some pretty pictures using a graphing software. See here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y3zeqnnybk
Is the idea that as we let "the square" grow it eventually hits the top of the square? Because for small squares $y=x^2$ and $y=x^3$ we won't hit the square.

Comment: @Mason it depends: $y = x$ always hits exactly the corner, no matter what type of zooming we use. $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ also don't change according to zooming. $x^2$ doesn't hit the top on zooming in, but eventually hits it on zooming out.

Comment: @Mason woah, thanks for that link! I So I guess the question would be: given that square, what functions intersect it on top as it gets infinitely bigger?

Comment: @shintuku: So, to be clear ... You're considering squares with vertices $(\pm k,\pm k)$, and you're interested in graphs that meet the top edge of every such square (ie, they reach $y=k$ for some $x$-value(s) between $x=-k$ and $x=+k$) for certain (ranges of?) $k$. Is this close?

Comment: @Blue right! my issue would be, how exactly do I evaluate whether there is such an intersection?

Comment: I just realized: if a function's derivative is eventually greater than one, it will intersect the top side, or at least, this is a working definition! thanks for the help!!

Comment: @Mason thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the top of your square is $y=k$ and what we want is that there exists some constant $C$ such that $\forall k>C, \exists x<k$ such that $f(x)=k$. I'm not sure that this characterization is any more than interpreting your geometrically posed question into symbols.